# What is order of evaluation for @Autowiring in SpringBoot project

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm trying to write a simple SprintBoot REST Controller to run on Websphere Liberty, and having a problem with @Autowire.   Here are the relevant (I think) pieces of code:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "userSetting")
public class RESTInterface {

    @Autowired
    private UserSettingDAO userSettingDAO;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/getUserSetting", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String getUserSetting(
            @RequestParam(value="user_id", required=true ) String user_id, 
            @RequestParam(value="app_id", required=true )  String app_id,
            @RequestParam(value="dashboard_name", required=true ) String dashboard_name 
            ) {
        if ( userSettingDAO == null ) {
            System.out.println( "userSettingDAO is null" );
    ...

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Component
 public class UserSettingDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

     public UserSettingDAO() {
        System.out.println( "dataSource is " + dataSource );
        System.out.println( "jdbcTemplate is " + jdbcTemplate );
```

When I deploy the application to Liberty, it appears to start up OK.
When I hit the appropriate endpoint, I see the following in `console.log`:

```
UserSettingDAO.jdbcTemplate = null
dataSource is null
jdbcTemplate is null
2018-04-24 16:54:19.887  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/userSetting/getUserSetting],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ui.usersetting.restinterface.RESTInterface.getUserSetting(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-04-24 16:54:19.890  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/userSetting/upsertUserSetting],methods=[POST],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public void com.ui.usersetting.restinterface.RESTInterface.upsertUserSetting(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-04-24 16:54:19.891  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/userSetting/deleteUserSetting],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public void com.ui.usersetting.restinterface.RESTInterface.deleteUserSetting(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-04-24 16:54:19.893  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/userSetting/hello],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ui.usersetting.restinterface.RESTInterface.hello()
2018-04-24 16:54:19.924  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-04-24 16:54:19.925  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-04-24 16:54:20.166  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6a5997f7: startup date [Tue Apr 24 16:54:15 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-24 16:54:21.386  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-04-24 16:54:21.389  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-04-24 16:54:21.396  INFO 8807 --- [cutor-thread-11] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
```

My question is:  Why are the two `println` statements saying that their respective variables are null?  Does it have something to do with the fact that the UserSettingDAO constructor appears in the log to be executed *before* the lines about `dataSource` appear in the log?

What *should* I do to get those variables properly initialized?

Comment: do you have a `spring.datasource.url` configured in your application.properties?  Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html for reference

Comment: Yes, along with `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`, `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password`.

Comment: I'd really suggest to use Java EE APIs, like JAX-RS, CDI, JPA on Liberty instead of Spring Boot. It is better integrated and supported, also by tooling.

Answer (score 0):

At the time a Spring component's constructor is called, any `@Autowired` objects will still be null.  This is because the spring container needs to initialize an instance of the class before it can inject values into the `@Autowired` fields.

I don't know how Spring implements injection, but most Java injection works something like this:

1. Construct new instance of the bean class, normally by invoking default ctor (or initializing a dynamically generated sub-class proxy)
2. Obtain objects that need to be injected into the bean
3. Using reflection/proxy, set the fields on the bean

To validate this, I created a method on `UserSettingsDAO` that utilizes the `@AutoWired` fields:

```
@Component
public class UserSettingDAO {

   @Autowired
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private DataSource ds;

   public UserSettingDAO() {
       System.out.println("ctor/jdbcTemplate is " + jdbcTemplate );
       System.out.println("ctor/datasource is: " + ds);
   }

   public void doStuff() {
       System.out.println("doStuff/jdbcTemplate is " + jdbcTemplate );
       System.out.println("doStuff/datasource is: " + ds);
   }
}
```

If we inject this DAO into another class and use it, we will see that the fields are initialized after the `UserSettingDAO` is constructed:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class RESTInterface {

    @Autowired
    private UserSettingDAO dao;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/jdbc", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String jdbc() {
        return dao.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Checking logs, this will produce the following output:

```
ctor/jdbcTemplate is null
ctor/datasource is: null
doStuff/jdbcTemplate is org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@4eb46bed
doStuff/datasource is: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@727d23c5
```